# Validation in model not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Driving me crazy.... validation not firing.

When I leave the field blank and hit submit it behaves as if the model were valid.

I have used dbFirst entity framework to create the model and added the required data annotation after the fact.

My Model (Entity)

```
public partial class Certificate
{
    public Certificate()
    {
        this.Travelers = new HashSet<Traveler>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your card number.")]
    public string CertificateNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BuyerID { get; set; }
    public string Used { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Traveler> Travelers { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Certificate CertificateNumber)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Travelers");
        }
        return View(); 

    }
```

My View:

```
@model GrandCelebration.Models.Certificate
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Validation";
}

<div>
    <h2>Please enter your card number below to validate</h2>
    <div id="searchbar">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CertificateNumber)
        <input type="submit" class="btn" alt="Validate" style="display:inline" value="Validate" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificateNumber)
        </fieldset>
        }
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the required js files?

Comment: in the layout im pretty sure

Comment: whiich files should be there?

Comment: Can't remember the filenames off the top of my head, but they're enabled in the web.config

Comment: That was it....they weren't n the layout...Thank you

Comment: How do i give u credit for your answer?

Comment: You can't unless I post an answer, which I won't do because you fixed it yourself really - I appreciate the thought though!

Comment: Ok, now i may have something u can post an answer for. Its validating fine for an empty field but returning The Value is Invalid for whatever I post. any ideas?

Comment: @markpsmith: Telling the OP to include the client-side validation scripts in the layout *is* an answer to the question. If that's what was required to fix the problem, then that's what was required. Unless an answer is posted and accepted, then question remains open and continues to show up in the unanswered list.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - fair point, I hadn't actually considered that.

Comment: @DougFarrell - not sure what's causing that new problem, might be related to the GET method that displays the view.  Probably best to ask a new question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the required js files weren't included.

Firstly make sure that unobtrusive validation is enabled in Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Then include 3 js files in the _Layout page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When cient-side validation is successfully enabled, if you look at the textbox HTML you will see a `data-val` property has been added.

Comment: I simply added the jqueryval bundle which was missing from the layout. The web config was fine. the next issue was caused by the db not allowing nulls into the InsertDate field which is populated on the db side using getdate(). Problem persists because I do allow nulls but thedate is not being populated when the record is created.